# in ubuntu 12.04 make cannot find Qt libraries

Tags: qt, ubuntu, static-libraries

When I run make (after running qmake) I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQtGui
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQtCore
```

In synaptic it shows that I have installed libqtcore4 and libqtgui4.

There is no such directory as /usr/bin/ld.

Basically, I've installed the QtSDK, and QtCreator seems to work fine in that it can build the hello world program. But I want to be able to work from the CLI and run make. I suspect that I may need to redirect the make program to look elsewhere for QtGui and QtCore. If so, how do I find out where those libraries are? I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and I've followed the advice of this page http://www.qtforum.org/article/28081/installing-qt-4-5-2-on-linux.html down to the last section where it talks about libraries. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you don't have `/usr/bin/ld` you have some serious issues.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Install Qt using apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-core libqt4-gui
```

or if you want everything

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-*
```

Answer (score 5):

The advice at http://www.qtforum.org/article/28081/installing-qt-4-5-2-on-linux.html is outdated and useless in your case since you have a recent version of Ubuntu. It leads to having two different versions of Qt side by side, which is technically possible but hard to manage.

You should install the [qtcreator](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/qtcreator) Ubuntu package and just delete the `/opt/qtsdk...` directory and undo the modifications suggested by the outdated instructions. It is essential that your `PATH` is not tweaked so that it's the Ubuntu version of `qmake` that is found when called from the command line.

If you still have compilation problems after that, they're likely to be solved by installing more packages, such as **libqt4-dev** or others Qt-related packages.

Also, /usr/bin/ld is not a directory, it's the linker program.