# Qt executable runs without libarys?

Tags: qt, ubuntu, shared-libraries, executable

this is actually no problem but the opposite. Since I don't realy understand what exactly happens here, I wanted to ask you. :)

I've written a QT application on Windows, copied the project to a vritual Ubuntu (12.04) and build the whole thing with GCC for 64bit. I also have some other libarys next to Qt include. (PortAudio for audio playback)

Now I only copied the executable to a freshly installed Ubuntu with no Qt installed. (I just installed it, 14.04) and it runs.

I used Qt Creator to build my project. Does it only include static libarys or why is the application working without shared objects?

I am no regular linux user so I have nearly no experience in building linux executalbes. ;)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is that this version of **Ubuntu** has the runtime library pre-installed. Just open the package manager and look for **libqt4** I guess. [Perhaps check this answer too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11094661/129130). Or did you use static linking by mistake?

Comment: You are right! :D I am using the newest version of ubuntu so I didn't thought they had the libaries preinstalled. (Qt5 as well)

So for PCs where Qt isnt isntalled, is it sufficient to just copy the right .so-files to the executable? (doesn't have to look good. ;D)