# Make linker find qt5

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, linker, qt5

I am new to computing world. I am trying to install [iai kinect2 drivers](https://github.com/code-iai/iai_kinect2) but while executing the `catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release"` step I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQt5::Core
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQt5::Gui
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQt5::Widgets
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQt5::Test
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQt5::Concurrent
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQt5::OpenGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/pb/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libkinect2_registration.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [iai_kinect2/kinect2_registration/CMakeFiles/kinect2_registration.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

After doing a lot of stackoverflowing I figured out that either the [qt5 is not downloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094619/in-ubuntu-12-04-make-cannot-find-qt-libraries) or downloaded in some other directory or conflicting with other version of qt4. Some of the pages on [github](https://github.com/googlecartographer/cartographer_ros/issues/119) also suggested a patch but that was for another package.

I have already installed qt5 but in my home directory since I followed the steps on the [Qt5 webpage](https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu). Now how can I add the path of installed Qt5 libraries so that the linker (ld) can find the required files.

Useful links - [Qt5 linker issue](http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/Qt5-linker-issues-td5726964.html), [Linker error cannot find lqt5::Widgets](http://forum.freecadweb.org/viewtopic.php?t=15646), [similar error launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vtk6/+bug/1451806)

Note - I am using Ubuntu 14.04, in case you want me to update some $VAR then kindly suggest its name like $LIBRARY_DIR. And if you want me to add the -DVAR='path' to catkin_make then also suggest a proper variable name that I need to add.

Thank you so much!! :D

Comment: I put on an answer, isn't worked?

Answer (score 1):

What about just installing `qtbase5-dev` package (should be Qt 5.2.1 for Ubuntu 14.04):

```
sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev
```

instead of your installation of [Qt5](https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu)?

In case you prefer to just fix the library path you can add a file *whatever.conf* in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` adding one or more rows with pathnames for the libraries.
After that, run `ldconfig` in there.

Comment: Will installing it again via apt-get create conflict with the old one? And generally the qt5 package is quite heavy (in terms of size) that's why I don't want to repeat it. However, I will try the library path fix. In the /etc/ld.so.conf.d there are many other .conf files like x86_64-linux-gnu.conf, libc.conf, etc. Which else .conf should I add to this folder or shall I edit an existing .conf file?

Comment: Just use a name of your choice: all `.conf` files in there are read. For example `qt5pallav.conf`.

Comment: I just tried adding whatever.conf file and appending the path of the qt5 library. Still the same problem :(

Comment: I performed the `ldconfig` as well but in vain. I even installed the `qtbase5-dev` along with `qt5-default` as mentioned on the [Ubuntu web](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/qt5-default) but no solution. I even deleted the iai_kinect2 workspace and cloned it again and repeated the whole procedure. Nothing solved the problem yet. But thank you so much for your help.

Comment: As a last resort you can try to add `LIBS += -L<library path>` to the Qt `.pro` file.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.
You can follow the steps given below for fixing the problem:

Firstly download the necessary libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5concurrent5
sudo apt-get install libqt5test5
sudo apt-get install libqt5core5a
sudo apt-get install libqt5opengl5
sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-dev
```

Then add these lines to `'<consider-package>/CMakeLists.txt'`:

```
find_package(Qt5Gui)
find_package(Qt5Core)
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
find_package(Qt5Test)
find_package(Qt5Concurrent)
find_package(Qt5OpenGL)
```

Finally do `catkin_make`.